# How to write in nasm without writing null bytes?

Tags: file, null, byte, nasm

Pretty simple problem.

This nasm is supposed to write a user-written message (i.e. hello) to a file, again determined by user input from an argument. It does this just fine, but the problem is, it writes all the null bytes not used afterwards as well. For example, if I reserve 32 bytes for user input, and the user only uses four for his input, those for bytes will be printed, along with 28 null bytes.

How do I stop printing null bytes?

Code used:

```
global _start

section .text
_start:

    mov rax, 0 ; get input to write to file
    mov rdi, 0
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 32
    syscall

    mov rax, 2 ; open the file at the third part of the stack
    pop rdi
    pop rdi
    pop rdi
    mov rsi, 1
    syscall

    mov rdi, rax

    mov rax, 1 ; write message to file
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 32
    syscall

    mov rax, 3 ; close file
    syscall

    mov rax, 1 ; print success message
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, output
    mov rdx, outputL
    syscall

    mov rax, 60 ; exit
    mov rdi, 0 
    syscall

section .bss
    msg: resb 32

section .data
    output: db 'Success!', 0x0A
    outputL: equ $-output
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after doing some digging in header files and experimenting, I figured it out on my own.

Basically, the way it works is that you have to put the user's string through a byte counting process that counts along the string until it finds a null byte, and then stores that number of non-null bytes.

I'll post the workaround I'm using for anyone who's had the same problem as me. Keep in mind that this solution is for 64-bit nasm, **NOT 32**!

For 32-bit coders, change:

- all instances of "rax" with "eax"
- all instances of "rdi" with "ebx"
- all instances of "rsi" with "ecx"
- all instances of "rdx" with "edx"
- all instances of "syscall" with "int 80h" (or equivelant)
- all instances of "r8" with "edx" (you'll have to juggle this and rdx)

Here's the solution I use, in full:

```
global _start

; stack: (argc) ./a.out input filename

section .text
_start:

getInput:
    mov rax, 0   ; syscall for reading user input
    mov rdi, 0  
    mov rsi, msg ; store user input in the "msg" variable
    mov rdx, 32  ; max input size = 32 bytes
    xor r8, r8   ; set r8 to zero for counting purposes (this is for later)

getInputLength:
    cmp byte [msg + r8], 0 ; compare ((a byte of user input) + 0) to 0
    jz open                ; if the difference is zero, we've found the end of the string
                           ; so we move on. The length of the string is stored in r9.
    inc r8                 ; if not, onto the next byte...
    jmp getInputLength     ; so we jump back up four lines and repeat!

open:
    mov rax, 2 ; syscall for opening files
    pop rdi
    pop rdi
    pop rdi    ; get the file to open from the stack (third argument)
    mov rsi, 1 ; open in write mode
    syscall

    ; the open syscall above has made us a full file descriptor in rax

    mov rdi, rax ; so we move it into rdi for later

write:
    mov rax, 1   ; syscall for writing to files
                 ; rdi already holds our file descriptor
    mov rsi, msg ; set the message we're writing to the msg variable
    mov rdx, r8  ; set write length to the string length we measured earlier
    syscall

close:
    mov rax, 3 ; syscall for closing files
               ; our file descriptor is still in fd
    syscall

exit:
    mov rax, 60 ; syscall number for program exit
    mov rdi, 0  ; return 0
```

Keep in mind that this is not a complete program. It totally lacks error handling, offers no user instruction, etc. It is only an illustration of method.

Comment: 32-bit code also uses different system call numbers in EAX, like `__NR_write` is 4 in `asm/unistd_32.h` vs. `1` in `asm/unistd_64.h`.  Also, your code never actually makes a `read` system call, despite the comments.  And this source still references a `msg` symbol which it doesn't define.  `read` returns the number of byte read, in RAX. (Or negative for error).  So that makes it unnecessary to scan the string for a `0` byte, unless you want to truncate the input if it contains `0`s like from `find -print0`.   It looks from comments like you wanted to use a string from the command line, though.